# Shorter way to access name of class in static method?

Tags: php, class, php-5.3

Is there a better/shorter way to write the `whoAmI` method in the following code? It seems a bit unnecessary to create a new object just to get the static class' name.

```
<?php

abstract class baseClass {
    static function whoAmI() {
        echo get_class(new static); // Making a new class just to get its name???
    }
}
```

Comment: I love that you use such a verbose way of finding the static class' name, and have the username 'too much php' =) Good question though, I hadn't come across `get_called_class()` before (from the accepted answer, from Erlend).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `get_called_class()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php